# How to put a css style in a php "echo'ed" html table td?

Tags: php, html, css, echo

This causes my entire page to be displayed as a white screen. I'm geussing I'm using "'s or ''s incorrectly.

```
echo "<td nowrap="wrap" style="width:100px;"><center>" . $row['probdis'] . "</center></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It appears your question is just about syntax errors. While you're unversed with the language, please use an editor with syntax highlighting. Also look at the escaping rules in the manual http://php.net/string

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just a few things to note. Depending on the doctype you're using (which should be the HTML5 doctype unless you have a specific reason not to use it) you shouldn't use the nowrap attribute. It's been deprecated in HTML4.01 and isn't supported at all in HTML5. The same is true for the `<center>` tag. Instead, you should use CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You are not escaping your quotes, the correct is:

```
echo "<td nowrap=\"wrap\" style=\"width:100px;\"><center>" . $row['probdis'] . "</center></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to either use single quotes

```
echo "<td nowrap='wrap' style='width:100px;'><center>" . $row['probdis'] . "</center></td></tr>";
```

or escape your double quotes

```
echo "<td nowrap=\"wrap\" style=\"width:100px;\"><center>" . $row['probdis'] . "</center></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, an echo statement must use the same type of apostrophe or quotation marks to open and close the output. Apostrophes (`'`) mean that no internal parsing will be done by PHP, whereas quotes (`"`) mean that the output will be parsed. By *parsed* I mean that PHP will look for variables to output.

Your code should be:

```
echo '<td nowrap="wrap" style="width:100px;"><center>' . $row['probdis'] . '</center></td></tr>';
```

Just a note, if you have a variable you want to include in output you can do it one of two ways:

```
echo 'My variable is ' . $x . '.';
```

or

```
echo "My variable is $x.";
```

The latter case demonstrates parsing, and simplifies concatenation.

Note that if you are using apostrophes, quotation marks *internal* to the string do not require an escape character and do not end the output of echo. The same is true in reverse, if you use quotation marks, then internal apostrophes do not require escape characters nor end the output.

Realize when you are outputting HTML, you have to also output quotation marks that will be read by the client (browser) so it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
echo '<td nowrap="wrap" style="width:100px"><center>' . $row["probdis"] . '</center></td></tr>';
```